# Meaning of unsigned char (*pArray[10][10]);

Tags: c++, c

What does the following declaration mean?

```
unsigned char (*pArray[10][10]);
```

Comment: The braces have no effect in this declaration. Are you sure you reproduced it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) says:

*declare pArray as array 10 of array 10 of pointer to unsigned char*

Basically what you did was to declare a 2-D Array of pointers.

See this question:

[Equivalent C declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436350/equivalent-c-declarations/5437715#5437715)

Now try to parse this:

`int **(*f)(int**,int**(*)(int **,int **));`

*[ In your mind of course ]*

Comment: That's simple... pointer to function that returns an `int**`, and takes two arguments, an `int**` and a pointer to a function that takes two `int**` as arguments and return another `int**`... Adding a few arrays there would make it a little more interesting... `int *(*p( int** ))[10]`, as one of the function arguments...

Comment: @David::Hmm.. how about this:
`int **(*f)(int**,int**([5])(int **,int **[5]))[5]();`

Answer (score 4):

Declaration

```
unsigned char (*pArray[10][10]);
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
unsigned char *pArray[10][10];
```

The parentheses are entirely redundant and have no effect at all. This is a 2D 10x10 array of `unsigned char *` pointers.

Comment: "entirely redundant and have no effect at all" - isn't that phrasing a bit redundant? :)

Comment: Well, every time I think about redundancy I always come up with such excessive phrasing all the time without a single exception :)

Comment: At least AndreyT is not an Oxymoron.haha

Comment: I can weasel my way out of this: in case of `int ((*p))[10]` braces are redundant but do have effect (i.e. the extra pair of braces is redundant, but in general braces matter), while in case or `int ((p))` the braces are both redundant and have no effect :)

Answer (score 0):

[www.cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org) says:

> declare pArray as array 10 of array 10 of pointer to unsigned char