Confusion to interpret declarations in C
I'm working on improving my C programming skills and have encountered a confusing aspect related to pointer declarations. I'm hoping to gain a better understanding of the differences between these two statements:
int *ptr[3];
int (*ptr)[3];

While they may appear similar at first glance, I believe there are significant differences in their meanings and implications. I would appreciate it if you could help me understand:

The fundamental differences between these two declarations
How to differentiate between them, considering their syntactical similarities
The rules or conventions in C that guide the interpretation of these statements

I am confused between these two. I think that I am lacking some concept related to interpretation of these declarations. Please try to explain where am I lacking or what part should I study more? What concepts I may have missed?

Enter these declarations at cdecl.org - are any questions remaining?

Welcome to SO. There are no conversions involved here.

The main term for you to research is operator precedence. [] have higher precedence than the *

You can find explanations like http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html but decoding the more complex messes is not necessarily an essential skill. If in doubt, use a tool like cdecl.

@Armali: cdecl.org does not tell you the rules for interpreting declarations.

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436350/equivalent-c-declarations

You may find this answer most helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915735/4593267

How symbols are grouped in C is determined by the language grammar. The ordering of operators is informally called precedence, but it is formally specified by mathematical rules in the C standard. These rules say that, in * ptr [3], ptr and [3] are grouped together before *. So *ptr[3] is effectively * (ptr[3]).
A declaration gives a “picture” of how a variable will be used.1 int *ptr[3] says “When *ptr[i] is used in an expression, it is an int.” From this, we can derive the type of ptr, as shown below.
For int *ptr[3], which is grouped as int * (ptr[3]):

Since *ptr[i] is an int, (ptr[i]) must be a pointer to an int.
Since (ptr[i]) is a pointer to int, ptr[i] must also be a pointer to int.
Since ptr[i] is a pointer to an int, ptr must be an array of pointers to int.

For int (*ptr)[3]:

Since (*ptr)[i] is an int, (*ptr) must be an array of int.
Since (*ptr) is an array of int, *ptr must also be an array of int.
Since *ptr is an array of int, ptr must be a pointer to an array of int.

Question about the rules

The rules or conventions in C that guide the interpretation of these statements

The grammar rules are specified in the C standard in Backus-Naur form. The official rules are scattered throughout the standard, appearing where the things they apply to are discussed, but there is a summary in Annex A, in clause A.1.
The rules for declarations are in clause 6.7. The grammar for arrays and pointers in declarations is in 6.7.6 1. In particular, the rule for a declarator is:

declarator: pointeropt direct-declarator

and the rule for a direct-declarator includes (with some detail omitted):

direct-declarator: direct-declarator [ assignment-expressionopt ]

This means that, when a compiler is analyzing C source code, it must resolve direct-declarator first, because the direct-declarator is used in resolving the declarator. So the [3] in the direct-declarator must be grouped first, before the compiler groups it with the pointer in the declarator.
There are actually different grammar rules for expressions and declarations, but they parallel each other to give the same grouping for the relevant symbols. The expressions in clause 6.5 are listed in order of how the grammar rules bind them, so the order they appear in 6.5 can be taken as a precedence table.
Footnote
1 Kernighan and Ritchie, The C Programming Language, 1978, page 90.

These statements are fundamentally different, let me explain why.
int *ptr[3] declares an array that contains 3 pointers to variables of type int. This happens because, as Gerhardh explained in their comment, the [] operator has a higher precedence than *.
Parentheses, of course, play an important role in operator precedence. By typing int (*ptr)[3], the order will be inverted an you will declare a pointer, which points to an entire array that contains 3 ints. I hope this helped you!


int *ptr[3]; declare ptr as an array of 3 pointers to integers
int (*ptr)[3]; declare ptr as a pointer to an array of 3 integers

To differentiate them, remember that if the syntax involves brackets [] directly after the variable name then it is an array, but if brackets are used in parentheses (), it's a pointer to an array.
